# Getting physical address when you don't have the page in physical memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, mips, paging

For the record, this is homework.

I have a problem, where I have a processor that uses 32 bit virtual addresses and 32 bit physical addresses, with 4Kb pages and a linear page table.

I am given the following assembly instruction (MIPS32)

```
lw $t0, 0x34c8($zero)
```

Since, this processor uses 4Kb pages, the offset in the virtual address is 12 bits long, and therefore the last nibble in the address is the VPN (3). Using that to query the page table, I found that the PTE is an empty entry:

```
VPN | Dirty | Present | PPN
----------------------------
0   |   1   |   0     | 0x1
----------------------------
1   |   0   |   1     | 0x0
----------------------------
2   |   1   |   1     | 0x6
----------------------------
3   |   -   |   0     | -
----------------------------
4   |   0   |   1     | 0x4
----------------------------
5   |   0   |   1     | 0x2
----------------------------
6   |   0   |   1     | 0x7
----------------------------
7   |   0   |   1     | 0x3
```

How do I find the physical address, then? I'm told all physical pages in memory are in use, but I don't know if that helps. Am I supposed to assume the PPN is going to be 0x5, since that's the only "missing" page number not in the table?

Thanks.

Comment: It might help if you define VPN, PTE and PPN, so that people familiar with the concepts but on different platforms, or from a CS class 20 years ago, are better able to help.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework, but to help with specific problems you have when writing your solution. Give it a go yourself, and if you get stuck get back to us with a very specific question.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: I have given it a go, that's precisely why I ask about what I do next, since it's blocking me.